# PHP: Twitter API not taking all sentence

Tags: php, twitter

I am using *Twitter API's* hashtag search mechanism. I am taking tweets by hashtags but I am not taking all sentence when its long it show me ... in the end. I want to show all of this sentence what should I do ?

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23".$hashtag."&count=2");
foreach($tweets->statuses as $tweet){

$twetler=$tweet->text;

echo $twetler;

$parcalar = preg_split('/\s+/',$twetler);

    print_r($parcalar);

    $parcasayisi=count($parcalar);

 for($i=0;$i<$parcasayisi;$i++){
     if($parcalar[$i]=="terrible"]){
         echo "BAD";
     }
 } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you use this code instead?

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23".$hashtag."&count=2&tweet_mode=extended");
```